# How to work around Python object that does not support indexing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, fractions

**Objective:** to have two elements that can be called later in a script

**Description:** In the example below, I am only interested in the 0.25 value which will is represented by 1/4). I would like to have a value for the [numerator](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerator) (1) and the [denominator](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denominator) (4). I am making use of Python's [fractions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module.

```
NUMBER = 5.25

from fractions import Fraction
import math

def express_partFraction(NUMBER):
    part = math.modf(NUMBER)[0] 
    return ((Fraction(part)))

express_partFraction(NUMBER)
```

Currently, I have the following returned which is not indexable:

```
Fraction(1, 4)
```

However, I am looking for something like the following:

```
numerator = express_partFraction(NUMBER)[0]
denominator = express_partFraction(NUMBER)[1]
```

Which generates this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-486-39196ec5b50b> in <module>()
     10 express_partFraction(NUMBER)
     11 
---> 12 numerator = express_partFraction(NUMBER)[0]
     13 denominator = express_partFraction(NUMBER)[1]

TypeError: 'Fraction' object does not support indexing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 2.7 documentation omits the fact that `Fraction` objects have `numerator` and `denominator` attributes. You can find them in [the Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.numerator).

If you want to see what attributes an unknown object has, just use the `dir()` function:

```
>>> x = Fraction(1, 2)
>>> x.numerator
1
>>> x.denominator
2
>>> [a for a in dir(x) if not a.startswith('_')]
['conjugate', 'denominator', 'from_decimal', 'from_float', 'imag', 'limit_denominator', 'numerator', 'real']
```

Comment: It's technically documented, since the docs say "The Fraction class inherits from the abstract base class numbers.Rational, and implements all of the methods and operations from that class." It's not a particularly *good* way of documenting it, but it's technically there.

Answer (score 1):

Fraction objects have `numerator` and `denominator` attributes:

```
numerator = some_fraction.numerator
denominator = some_fraction.denominator
```

The fact that you're inputting a float will cause you problems, though:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction(0.1)
Fraction(3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)
```

There's `limit_denominator`, which you can use to take a guess at what the fraction "should" be by assuming the denominator isn't too big, but you should really try to avoid a floating-point step entirely. For example, take input as a string:

```
>>> fractions.Fraction('1.1')
Fraction(11, 10)
>>> fractions.Fraction('1.1') % 1
Fraction(1, 10)
>>> _.numerator
1
```